# Invalid Binary File after uploading on ITunesConnect

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, app-store

I have built an iPhone application and was uploading the 4th version when the Invalid Binary status showed up on ITunes Connect. The 1st 3 versions uploaded smoothly.

I recieved a mail from Apple with the following error

**Invalid File Name** - Your package contains a file 'appname.app/Icon ' with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names.

I am unable to zero down on the trouble making file. Any leads on how I could debug this? Have been stuck on it for 2 days now.

Comment: I think it's because of the "/" in the file name. Don't use chars like "/" or "." for your files' name

Answer (score 3):

App icon file must be named `Icon.png`. It appears that your binary includes a file with incorrect name or a space in between. Check the app icon file's name.

Also check your XCode project for any stray file with name `Icon .png`. Sometimes due to version control softwares there can be some hidden files backup with strange name. Check for **hidden** files/folders with name `Icon .` in your XCode project. Any such files getting included in your XCode project will get added in the app binary resources.

Comment: Thanks.. That was the reason

Comment: thank you, 4 me their was something wrong with the app naming

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found the `Icon .png` making a search in the filter of the `Project Navigator`

[image: filter inside Project Navigator]

I delete it and it worked.