# iOS issue found during validation - invalid characters

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store, app-store-connect

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I found a post where someone had a similar issue and a solution was found, however, I'm still running into a wall:

[Invalid Binary File after uploading on ITunesConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460314/invalid-binary-file-after-uploading-on-itunesconnect)

The exact error I get is the same, i.e. "Your package contains a file 'App Name.app/Icon ' with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I'm almost 100% certain all I need to do is find the offending file named "Icon .png" (the space before the .png is what messes everything up, I'm assuming) but I can't seem to find it. In the above post, looking into hidden files and folders was suggested but I'm not sure how to go about this as I've never done it before.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried searching for that file name in the project directory?

Comment: Yes, I've searched everywhere I know how to search

Answer (score -1):

If you are using external font, or external libraries sometimes they have an exe file named icon, go to your external folders and make sure you delete that file, you've probably been searching for images that's why you haven't found the exe file