# Error in publishing the app through application loader

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am receiving this error

> ERROR ITMS-90328: "Your package contains a file
>   'ABC.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/he.lproj/Icon '
>   with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control
>   characters in the file names."

And alot of same errors.

I tried to rename them through terminal and Icon.png but still it doesnt work.

Can you please help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you check you project folder may be project folder contains some copies of icon with wrong name format.?

Comment: when i first checked it the name was "Icon?" i then renamed it to "Icon" and it didnt work then i renamed it again to "Icon.png" and still it didnt work :(

Comment: see the following [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460314/invalid-binary-file-after-uploading-on-itunesconnect]

Comment: here is also suggestion to resolve this error on the bottom of the discussion[https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/43349-error-messages-after-trying-to-upload-to-apple/]

Comment: wanted to add this for future googlers, I had the same error due to a SPACE that was inserted (probably by me / accident) at the end of the application name. It gets all the way to upload completed before erroring.