# Getting error "your binary file is invalid" when uploading to iOS app store

Tags: ios, xcode

My issue is with uploading the iOS application to the app store. When I go to upload the application it automatically goes through a validation process and stops at the “verifying assets” stage, then shows an error that says “your binary file is invalid.” The error code is ITMS-90680.

Can anyone help with this error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do one thing, just add all sizes of the app icon.

or Do:

1) Revoke Distribution Certificate.

2) Launch Keychain Access > Certificates and remove all of the expired Certificates (If you a find few of them)

3) Create a new certificate and install.

For further [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460314/invalid-binary-file-after-uploading-on-itunesconnect) and [also this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823926/itms-9000-the-binary-you-upload-was-invalid).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16514141)

Comment: Basically, This answer is all about theory and other explanation. I found the same in that link. But I have concluded in my update.

Comment: My point is that if you're going to provide an answer, you should include enough detail in the answer that someone doesn't have to go elsewhere to see what you mean. A link is great, but only as a supplement to your answer. The relevant details need to be in your answer.